# How do I respond to user if I have no internet connection?

Tags: android, json, http, user-interface

I am trying to write the code that would read a JSONArray but there is a possibility that the internet server is down and the device is not able to connect or then there is no internet connection on the device.

How do I respond to user gracefully as return statement in my exception catch block don't seem to work.

Here is my code.

```
public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    JSONArray jArray = null;

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        if(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
            // Connection was established. Get the content. 
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            // A Simple JSON Response Read
            istream = httpEntity.getContent();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                   + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            Log.d(Constants.LOG, "httpEntity : ");
        }

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a `Toast` saying what the problem is. for example "Connection cannot be established"

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i do that:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)this.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo ni =cm.getActiveNetworkInfo(); 
        if(ni==null){
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
            dialog.setTitle("No Internet Connection");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            Button settings = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.settings);
            Button exit = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.exitApp);
            Button retry = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.retry);
            settings.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                }

            });
            exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialog.cancel();    
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                }

            });
            retry.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialog.cancel();    
                MainActivity.this.finish();
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
                }

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

How will a catch work if you have

```
throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
               + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
```

If your code tells the OS to throw it will throw, what else can you expect here ?

Comment: Thanks @Siddarth  - I didn't know how to go about as the website was down and my app was actually failing and closing. That was the reason I was trying to throw something and catch so that I can gracefully end my app after responding to the user that the website is down.  To have a good user interface it is better to respond to user with msg then crash an app.

Comment: Like iPhone I would not respond anything, just close silently. But if the device internet is down then I would put a message "check for your internet connection" and then close.